# How to set STANDALONE_CLIENT mode when try to distributed train with estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The code:

```
job_name = FLAGS.job_name
task_index = FLAGS.task_index

ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
chief_hosts = FLAGS.chief_hosts.split(",")
evaluator_hosts = FLAGS.evaluator_hosts.split(",")

tf.logging.info('Chief host is :%s' % chief_hosts)
tf.logging.info('PS hosts are: %s' % ps_hosts)
tf.logging.info('Worker hosts are: %s' % worker_hosts)
tf.logging.info('eval hosts are: %s' % evaluator_hosts)

cluster = {'chief': chief_hosts, "ps": ps_hosts,
           "worker": worker_hosts}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps(
    {'cluster': cluster,
     'task': {'type': job_name, 'index':
         task_index}})
```

```
dist_strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
        num_gpus=FLAGS.n_gpus,
        cross_device_ops=AllReduceCrossDeviceOps('nccl', num_packs=FLAGS.n_gpus),
        # cross_device_ops=AllReduceCrossDeviceOps('hierarchical_copy'),
    )
log_every_n_steps = 8
run_config = RunConfig(
        train_distribute=dist_strategy,
        eval_distribute=dist_strategy,
        log_step_count_steps=log_every_n_steps,
        model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
        save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps)

model_fn = model_fn_builder(
        bert_config=bert_config,
        init_checkpoint=FLAGS.init_checkpoint,
        learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate,
        num_train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
        num_warmup_steps=FLAGS.num_warmup_steps,
        use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
        use_one_hot_embeddings=FLAGS.use_tpu)

    # If TPU is not available, this will fall back to normal Estimator on CPU
    # or GPU.
estimator = Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        params={},
        config=run_config)
```

The log:

```
INFO:tensorflow:RunConfig initialized for Distribute Coordinator with INDEPENDENT_WORKER mode
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Only `STANDALONE_CLIENT` mode is supported when you call `estimator.train`
```

The version:

```
Linux OS
TF 1.15 or 1.14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow 1.15

For multi-GPU-multi-machine, use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` instead of `estimator.train` and remove `tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy`.

For multi-GPU-1-machine, use `estimator.train`.